RS.exe shared dataset (.rsd) deployment - invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/shareddatasetdefinition'
I'm trying to setup CI/CD automatic deployment of SSRS RDLs and RSDs. I'm using a batch file, VB script, and RS.exe to programmatically deploy from my local source control directories to a SSRS server. RDLs are working, but RSDs are failing

Unhandled exception: The definition of this report is not valid or
supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition
may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or
contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on
Reporting Services schemas.
Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/shareddatasetdefinition'
which cannot be upgraded.

I can manually deploy these rsd files, but RS.exe can't.  I've spent days trying to figure this out, does anyone have a clue? Is there another way to programmatically deploy shared datasets?
I can't find a library with another version of xmlns for shareddatasetdefinition
